# The label New not displayed on all new products magento 2

Tags: magento2, new-products

I installed the template **shop4u** and i see that just on one product the label new is displayed despite i set featured = true. Can any one explain to me this code:

```
if (($newsTo != '' || $newsFrom != '') && $_config->getAdvanced('show_newlabel')) {
        if (($newsTo != '' && $newsFrom != '' && $now >= $newsFrom && $now <= $newsTo) || ($newsTo == '' && $now >= $newsFrom) || ($newsFrom == '' && $now <= $newsTo)){ ?>
            <div class="label-product label-new">
            <span class="new-product-icon">
                <?php echo __('New'); ?>
            </span>
            </div>
        <?php }
    } ?>
```

specially **getAdvanced('show_newlabel'))** because the rest is clear. please any explanation and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this code `$_config->getAdvanced('show_newlabel'))` . In configuration there will be a field for `show new label` or not.

go to `store->configuration->your module configuration` and check for new label field .Its used for display new label or not.

Comment: yes it's "is featured" but why not displayed when i choose a date grater than to day to start the new product : just product news from today  are highlited with this label

Comment: @DevelopperMagento just echo these two variable $newsTo and $newsFrom and check which dates are you getting . Then just check condition

Answer (score 2):

`if (($newsTo != '' || $newsFrom != ''))` means **newsfromdate** or **newstodate** not be blank. You can set date from particular product.

`$_config->getAdvanced('show_newlabel')` this one like configuration to check label will be display on frontend or not. You can check it by `System->Configuration`